# Is an SLD necessary for each layer?

Tags: geoserver, sld

For GeoServer, it is necessary to create a new style for each different layer to load?

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having that is leading to this question

Answer (score 1):

No, it is perfectly acceptable to use the same style (generic) for every layer but then all your layers will look the same (a red square, a blue line, grey polygons, and simple rgb or greyscale rasters.

It really all depends on your use case.